# Display all the collisions in HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm new to HashMap in java. I'm trying to create a situation where collision takes place and for same key (1 in this case). I read that the values in HashMap are not over written, instead, they are maintained in a link list. How to display all the values of key "1"?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hash.put("1", "one");
        hash.put("1", "two");
        hash.put("1", "three");
        hash.put("1", "four");
        System.out.println(hash);
    }
```

The output of the above code -

```
{1=two}
```

Comment: Your scenario is not feasible

Comment: Perhaps, what you need is a multi valued map https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html

Answer (score 4):

That's not true. Only one key,value pair for each unique key is stored in the map. The latest value you put in the map for a specific key would override the previous value that was stored for that key.

Different keys might have the same hash code, which causes them to be stored in the same linked list inside the HashMap, but the keys in the map are all unique. For each two keys in the map `key1.equals(key2)` would return false, even if `key1.hashCode()==key2.hashCode()`.

Comment: So, if I have to store "Ca" and "DB" (both have same value for hashcode), what should I do?

And are "Ca" and "DB" keys or values? If they are values, what is the key then?

Comment: @user3554962 whether they are keys or values depends on whether they are the first or second argument passed to the put method. If they are keys, both of them would be stored in the hash map with their values, and it doesn't matter (in terms of functionality) that they have the same hashCode value. You may have a performance issue, though, if many keys would have the same hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 lines of Map javadoc explains it all.

```
public interface Map<K,V>
```

**An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.**

The javadoc for Map can be found here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: So, if I have to store "Ca" and "DB" (both have same value for hashcode), what should I do?

And are "Ca" and "DB" keys or values? If they are values, what is the key then?

Comment: Even if hashcode returns same value, "Ca".equals"DB" will fail and hence these will be considered as 2 different keys. There are no constraints on values. A may could have 10 different keys , all having same value